# Uber/OLA like MapView with multiple cars animating simultaneously

Tags: android, marker

I am trying to achieve a Vehicle Monitoring System in which the a list of cars location is shown in the map fragment. I was able to show the movement of the car ( Through a given set of Latitude and Longitude).But what I want to achieve is similar to Uber in which multiple cars move simultaneously that is if there in 10 cars all the 10 cars should move and rotate similar to uber.

```
 **MoveCar.java**

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MoveCar extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    Marker marker;
    private boolean isMarkerRotating = false;
    ArrayList<LatLng> listOfPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    int currentPt = 0;
    LatLng finalPosition;
    Marker mMarker;
    Marker mMarker2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        //new location details
        listOfPoints.add(new LatLng(30.701623, 76.684220));
        listOfPoints.add(new LatLng(30.702486, 76.685487));
        listOfPoints.add(new LatLng(30.703135, 76.684891));
        listOfPoints.add(new LatLng(30.703256, 76.685000));
        listOfPoints.add(new LatLng(30.703883, 76.685941));
        listOfPoints.add(new LatLng(30.703413, 76.685190));
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mapFragment == null) {
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            if (mapFragment != null) {
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                        loadMap(googleMap);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private void loadMap(GoogleMap map) {
        googleMap = map;

        mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(30.701623, 76.684220)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car_marker)));
     //   mMarker2 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(30.7021811,76.6850622)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car_marker)));


        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        //Code to move car along static latitude and longitude

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (currentPt < listOfPoints.size()) {
                //post again
                Log.d("tess", "inside run ");
                Location targetLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                targetLocation.setLatitude(listOfPoints.get(currentPt).latitude);
                targetLocation.setLongitude(listOfPoints.get(currentPt).longitude);
                animateMarkerNew(targetLocation, mMarker);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
                currentPt++;
            } else {
                Log.d("tess", "call back removed");
                //removed callbacks
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
            }
        }
    }, 3000);

        //Here move marker along real time updates
//        final RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
//        params.put("source_lattitude", "lat");
//        params.put("source_longitude", "long");
//        params.put("date", "date");
//
//        //new handler
//        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
//
//                LoopjHttpClient.post(getString(R.string.default_upload_website), params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
//                    @Override
//                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
//
//                        try {
//                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(responseBody));
//                            String status = jsonObject.getString("status");
//                            String text = jsonObject.getString("text");
//                            //reading json array
//                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
//                            String source = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("source");
//
//                            String[] latLong = source.split(",");
//                            Location location = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
//                            location.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(latLong[0]));
//                            location.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(latLong[1]));
//                            //calling method to animate marker
//                            animateMarkerNew(location, mMarker);
//                        } catch (JSONException e) {
//                            e.printStackTrace();
//                        }
//                    }
//
//                    @Override
//                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
//                        Log.d("onFailure", "onFailure");
//                    }
//                });
//
//                handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
//            }
//        }, 3000);

    }

    private void animateMarkerNew(final Location destination, final Marker marker) {

        if (marker != null) {

            final LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();
            final LatLng endPosition = new LatLng(destination.getLatitude(), destination.getLongitude());

            final float startRotation = marker.getRotation();
            final LatLngInterpolatorNew latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolatorNew.LinearFixed();

            ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
            valueAnimator.setDuration(3000); // duration 3 second
            valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    try {
                        float v = animation.getAnimatedFraction();
                        LatLng newPosition = latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, endPosition);
                        marker.setPosition(newPosition);
                        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(newPosition)
                                .zoom(15.5f)
                                .build()));

                        marker.setRotation(getBearing(startPosition, new LatLng(destination.getLatitude(), destination.getLongitude())));
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        //I don't care atm..
                    }
                }
            });
            valueAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);

                    // if (mMarker != null) {
                    // mMarker.remove();
                    // }
                    // mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(endPosition).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_car)));

                }
            });
            valueAnimator.start();
        }
    }

    private interface LatLngInterpolatorNew {
        LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b);

        class LinearFixed implements LatLngInterpolatorNew {
            @Override
            public LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b) {
                double lat = (b.latitude - a.latitude) * fraction + a.latitude;
                double lngDelta = b.longitude - a.longitude;
                // Take the shortest path across the 180th meridian.
                if (Math.abs(lngDelta) > 180) {
                    lngDelta -= Math.signum(lngDelta) * 360;
                }
                double lng = lngDelta * fraction + a.longitude;
                return new LatLng(lat, lng);
            }
        }
    }


    //Method for finding bearing between two points
    private float getBearing(LatLng begin, LatLng end) {
        double lat = Math.abs(begin.latitude - end.latitude);
        double lng = Math.abs(begin.longitude - end.longitude);

        if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
            return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)));
        else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude < end.longitude)
            return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 90);
        else if (begin.latitude >= end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
            return (float) (Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat)) + 180);
        else if (begin.latitude < end.latitude && begin.longitude >= end.longitude)
            return (float) ((90 - Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(lng / lat))) + 270);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**activitymain.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <fragment
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.sample.sishin.maplocation.MapsActivity" />
        <!--<LinearLayout-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/locationMarker"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_gravity="center"-->
            <!--android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"-->
            <!--android:gravity="center"-->
            <!--android:orientation="vertical" >-->

            <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/locationMarkertext"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_map"-->
                <!--android:gravity="center"-->
                <!--android:minWidth="250dp"-->
                <!--android:paddingLeft="2dp"-->
                <!--android:paddingRight="2dp"-->
                <!--android:text=" Set your Location "-->
                <!--android:visibility="gone"-->
                <!--android:textColor="@android:color/white" />-->

            <!--<ImageView-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/imageMarker"-->
                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:src="@drawable/car_marker" />-->
        <!--</LinearLayout>-->



    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

So far I was able to movement of a single car using static data. I want to do the same for many cars dynamically. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: just only call animateMarkerNew(targetLocation, mMarker);

please call animateMarkerNew for other marker

Comment: Could you please elaborate I couldn't get it